# cake php setting your custom url

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a cakephp 2.x .. my webapp url is like this **"http://www.myweb.com/"** .. so after then i am redirected a user to a gettingstarted page after login .. "http://www.myweb.com/users/gettingstarted"..... what i want is i want a url like this ..

```
 http://www.myweb.com/gettingstarted...
```

so in order to do this i cant make a controller name **gettingstarted** because in cakephp u cant create a controller if you dont have a similar table name in your db.. hope you get this ..may be it is possible .. but dont know how can i accomplish this ..

Comment: You *can* create a controller if you don't have a similar name in the db... But ignoring that, could you better explain what you want? I get that you want a `http://www.myweb.com/gettingstarted...` url, but that `gettingstarted`, do you want it to be an action in another controller? like `UsersController->gettingstarted`. Please clarify.

Comment: @Nunser sorry yup exactly...what i want is i want a url like this "com/gettingstarted".. in order to acheive this ..i have to make a controller which i dont want ... i have a function name gettingstarted in some other controller ... i want to call that function without controller name comes in the url ... for example i want redirection like this $this->redirect  $this->redirect('/gettingstarted');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a rule in `routes.php` (preferably before any other rules)

```
//this will send www.web.com/gettingstarted to UsersController->gettingStarted()
Router::connect('/gettingstarted',
                 array('controller' => 'users', 'action'=>'gettingstarted'));
//this is the default route for www.web.com
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
```

With that I'm assuming you have a `gettingstarted` action in your `UsersController`. Oh, and that you are not passing variables to the action. Otherwise the rule would be a bit different.

For all those "url changes" read the [Routes doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html). Knowing how to manage urls can be useful.

**EDIT**
If you want the user to be redirected to the getting started page after a successful login, change the login action of your UsersController

```
public function login() {
   //all your login actions
   //if user is logged in
   $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'gettingstarted'));
}
```

That will redirect you to `www.web.com/gettingstarted`

Comment: so yup .. you got me .. now the next question is should i replace this Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index')); .. because when i do this www.web.com.. i come up to my index page due to this url .. should i replace it with this.. i dont think so its a good idea .. because in index page i have a login page

Comment: That really depends on how you want your site to be (an doesn't have much to do with the other question really). If you want the "getting started" page to be the first page someone sees when entering "www.web.com", then you should replace it. But personally I don't recommend it, "getting started" is generally something you display on the index (as a link) to make the site more user-friendly, not a forced option that everyone sees, whether they already know how to get started or not. *But!* do not remove that rule completely, cake won't know what to do with "www.web.com" if you erase that rule.

Comment: ok thankyou for your tip ..so you are saying that after login i cant make the url like this 'www.web.com/gettingstarted' .. ok .. now it is possible only if i make a new controller of this and then put all the functionality on index function ... but the problem is .. cake is throwing erros saying that you dont have a table in your db name getting started

Comment: No no, you got me completely wrong. You *can* make the url like 'etc/gettingstarted' with the route I gave you in the answer. What I don't recommend is replacing the route you indicated in your comment with this new one. You can make a redirect to the "getting started" page after loging in, that has nothing to do with routes, is a simple redirect you place in your login action. Do not create a GettingStartedController, please, I beg you

Comment: hahha ok sorry Nunser ... so then suppose i replace my code with yours .. then when i type the url www.web.com.. how cakephp knows that i have to go to the users controller where there is a function name index() in which i have to display a login page

Comment: because after sucessfully login i want to display the gettingstarted function without the controller name in the url